# When I label axes in a subplot with shared axes, not all labels show after plotting with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When creating a two-panel subplot with shared axis, I can specify the label for each axes...

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, sharex=True)
axes[0].set_ylabel('ylabel-1')
axes[1].set_ylabel('ylabel-2')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

***However***, when I use Pandas to plot on those axes, the shared label goes missing

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, sharex=True)
pd.DataFrame([1,2,3]).plot(ax=axes[0])
pd.DataFrame([3,2,1]).plot(ax=axes[1])
axes[0].set_ylabel('ylabel-1')
axes[1].set_ylabel('ylabel-2')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

How can I get that label to show?

Comment: It's because you're using `sharey=True`. If `sharey=False`, then the label will show.

Comment: yes, but I want `sharey=True` so the ticks match on both.

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20759), the label exists, but it is not visible.

Add this line to get the label to be visible.

```py
axes[1].yaxis.get_label().set_visible(True)
```

For example:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, sharex=True)
pd.DataFrame([1,2,3]).plot(ax=axes[0])
pd.DataFrame([3,2,1]).plot(ax=axes[1])
axes[0].set_ylabel('xlabel')
axes[1].set_ylabel('ylabel')

axes[1].yaxis.get_label().set_visible(True)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]